# how to call Package Manager Console and execute Find-Package in visual studio extension

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, nuget-server, dotnet-cli

I'm developing a visual studio extension(vsix).

Now, I want to get a nuget package latest version. I only found one way by using `Package Manager Console`, `dotnet CLI` [still not support search command.](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8040)

So, how can I call `Package Manager Console` and execute `Find-Package` command, or is there another way can get package latest version from specific package source server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the way in below doc or not?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/api/query-for-all-published-packages

I built a simple VSIX with customer Command item, and it could use below code to perform search packages from NuGet(need to install Nuget.PackageManagement into your VSIX project first).

```
        List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>> providers = new List<Lazy<INuGetResourceProvider>>();
        providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV3());  // Add v3 API support
        //providers.AddRange(Repository.Provider.GetCoreV2());  // Add v2 API support
        PackageSource packageSource = new PackageSource("https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json");
        SourceRepository sourceRepository = new SourceRepository(packageSource, providers);
        PackageMetadataResource packageMetadataResource = await sourceRepository.GetResourceAsync<PackageMetadataResource>();
        IEnumerable<IPackageSearchMetadata> searchMetadata = await packageMetadataResource.GetMetadataAsync("JSON.net", true, true, null, NuGet.Common.NullLogger.Instance, CancellationToken.None);
        var a= searchMetadata.ToString();
```

Comment: :D thanks, It's helpful. I hadn't find this doc, I found [this][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/visual-studio-extensibility/nuget-api-in-visual-studio#ivspackageinstallerevents-interface]